# Trouble changing object property/value via variable in function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using VueJS and trying to use v-model. to connect checkboxes to values in an object:

```js
jobsChecked: {Baker: false, Cook: false, Miner: false}  // etc...
```

and the checkbox element:

```html
<div class="checkbox jobs" v-for="j in jobs" :key="j">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="filters.jobsChecked.j"
    @change="filterJobs(j)"> {{ j }}
  </label>
</div>
```

with filterJobs() firing when I click one of these boxes:

```js
filterJobs(j) {
  if (!this.filters.jobs.includes(j)) {
    this.filters.jobs.push(j);
    this.filters.jobsChecked[j] = true;
  } else {
    const index = (ele) => ele === j;
    const remove = this.filters.jobs.findIndex(index);
    this.filters.jobs.splice(remove, 1);
    this.filters.jobsChecked[j] = false;
  }
  console.log("jobs filters: ", this.filters.jobs);
  console.log("jobs checked: ", this.filters.jobsChecked);
}
```

**Expected output**: The function receives "j" which is read as the string "Baker". The syntax for modifying an Object's property works and checking "Baker" pushes Baker to the filters.jobs array AND uses *filters.jobsChecked.j* to make *filters.jobsChecked.Baker* = **true**

**Actual output**: The function receives "j" which is read as the string "Baker", pushes "Baker" into the filters.jobs array, but then **adds the key/value 'j: true' to filters.jobsChecked.**

My confusion comes in here where I am expecting that, since the rest of the function seems to be fully aware the 'j' is not actually the letter j, but instead a passed variable with the value of "Baker", it will know that "filters.jobsChecked.j" = "filters.jobsChecked.Baker" and using object modification syntax, it should change the value to true as I wrote.

I have been reading other posts and websites all night about this and nothing I found made any sense or seemed to englighten me on this situation. As far as I can see, I am writing it exactly as it should be and using [] square notation since it's a variable being passed in.
I also tried writing **['j']** but that also just ADDED the key value "j: false" to the object...

What am I missing here? I have a feeling it's something stupidly obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is invalid syntax for accessing the string contained in `j` in the context of an object property.

`filters.jobsChecked.j` is looking for a property named "j" on the `jobsChecked` object, but it doesn't exist.  Use bracket notation to evaluate `j` as a variable:

```js
filters.jobsChecked[j]
```